# Extracting exact field value from xml file and creating zip files based on each station type in unix using gzip

Tags: unix, xml

I have an xml file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UnitReport Qunatity="163" start-time="2012-06-22T07:00:01+00:00">
<Station guid="59A7C775-7A2F-4ABD-BD10-B82614D5B846">
<Property>
<ValueString name="StationType">HDA</ValueString>
</Property>
</Station>
<Operator name="Generic"/>
<Category name="NB HDD">
<Product part-no="04MJKG" serial-no="04MJKG26402313A00"/>
</Category>
<Property>
<ValueString name="Manufacturer Name">JAX</ValueString>
<ValueString name="Manufacturing Site">TXN</ValueString>
</Property>
<TestRun start-time="2012-06-22T07:00:01+00:00" grade="Pass" name="HDA">
<Property>
<ValueString name="Manufacturers_Part_Number">MQ01ABF050</ValueString>
</Property>
</TestRun>
</UnitReport>
```

Within a UNIX shell script I need to extract value of ValueString tag from an XML field, where name is StationType.
Based on each StationType value I need to create zip files. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to solve your problem? We expect a minimum amount of research effort into finding a solution yourself…

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/StationType/{s!<ValueString name="StationType">\(.*\)</ValueString>!\1!;p}' input.xml
```

You should really use a real XML parser, but I don't know of any command line based ones. The regex above will break if the ValueString element is broken across several lines.